# Python - Appending to 2D arrays within a for loop causes previous entries to be overwritten

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I've written a function to create 16, 16 dimensional vectors and put them into an array, but when I append to the array, I end up with the previous entry being overwritten.

```py
import math

empvec=[None]*16
vecset=[]

for g in range(16):
    tempvec=empvec
    for i in range(16):
        f=g%8+1
        if(bool((g)//8)):
            tempvec[i]=i*f
        else:
            tempvec[i]=i/f
    vecset.append(tempvec)

for g in range(16):
    print(vecset[g])
```

I have also tried creating an empty, 16 entry array and then setting the values using
`vecset[g]=tempvec` instead of appending, which also didn't work

Comment: @Nick - The issue here is with making a shallow copy of a list via assignment, not with multiplying a list.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 you're right - I didn't look closely enough at the code. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the list for each row. Your current code has all rows pointing to the same list (memory address).

Simple change needed

```
for g in range(16):
    tempvec=empvec[:]  #  <<< copy list
```